# GridSplitter stopped working after upgrading to .net 4

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have 2 rows, the second row contains a grid splitter, defined to work on previous and current.

On .net 3.5 every thing worked fine.

After upgrading to .net 4 the splitter thumb does not response to my attempts of dragging it.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the binding

I did binding to both of grid heights and probably some fix to .net 4 binding mechanism caused the problems, now it's all fine.